# How do I get a VMWare guest to boot to /dev/sda2?

Tags: vmware-esxi, partition, boot

I have a Windows 7 guest on VMWare ESXi 6.  My virtual disk containing the VM (Windows 7), has two partitions.  One is the recovery partition.  One is the regular OS.  I restored these from a Clonezilla image on the VM, not the host.

Since I could not get anything to boot in the VM, I used gparted and changed the `boot` flag to sda1, the recovery partition, and it booted fine.  I added the boot flag to sda2, and it never boots.  Not an error, nothing, just blank screen.  Everything else boots fine (cd, etc.).  I do not believe it is the "blank VMWare console" that is found in most searches.

Using the gparted live CD on this VM (I loaded the VM with the gparted live CD and booted into it for that vm), I can mount /dev/sda2, and I can `ls` the files, etc., so I know sda2 is good (at least for mounting), `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

EDIT: I saved an image from a laptop using Clonezilla.  The image contained the recovery partition and the main Windows partition.  I loaded VMWare ESXi, so I could use VSphere and because the Type-1 hypervisor is free.  I created a VM of the correct size and ran Clonezilla from the VM's CD (ran an iso in the datastore I uploaded.)

From there I restored.  I did this as partitions.  Saved local partitions.  Restored local partitions (to the VM).  This is because I can't save the whole disk in an image and expect it to shrink down the size of the VM on the laptop.

Comment: Why do you call it the "recovery" partition?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's the one from the manufacturer.

Comment: Eh? How did a virtual machine get such a partition? Did you P2V this? Tell us the whole story here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I edited it.

Comment: Not tempted to try using VMware's conversion tools?

Comment: @Chopper3 I don't know anything about them.  Which tool?

Comment: Google 'vmware converter'

Comment: Are you sure it's a recovery partition? From what you said it might be the boot partition (that Windows needs) it's usually 100mb in Windows 7.